# Is there a way/tool to check if port on extern Firewall is only open in one direction

Tags: tcp, firewall, salt-stack

I have the following Scenario: 
A Master Server where *salt-master* is installed and a Minion Server where *salt-minion* is installed in between those two servers there is a **Cisco ASA Firewall**.

The Firewall Admin told me he has opened both TCP 4505 and 4506 ports from the **minion server** ==> **master server** (only one direction)

Still i have problems connecting to the master server. So here comes my question is there a way to find out that the TCP 4505 und 4506 ports are opened? Master and Slave servers do not have iptables installed.

Comment: Err, try it both ways?

Comment: Tell that to the firewall Admin, Salt should work only in one direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671469/what-open-ports-are-required-on-firewall-to-allow-for-salt-stack-remote-executio

Comment: try to telnet to the IP:4505 or 4506 depending on where you use this command form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at the Salt troubleshooting: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/troubleshooting/minion.html

I'll summarize it here (**xx.xx.xx.xx** is the master IP)

(if port is *not open*):

```
root@minion ~ # nc -v -z xx.xx.xx.xx 4505
salt [xx.xx.xx.xx] 4505 (?) : Connection refused
root@minion ~ # nc -v -z xx.xx.xx.xx 4506
salt [xx.xx.xx.xx] 4506 (?) : Connection refused
```

(if port is *open*):

```
root@minion:~# nc -v -z xx.xx.xx.xx 4505
salt [xx.xx.xx.xx] 4505 (?) open
root@minion:~# nc -v -z xx.xx.xx.xx 4506
salt [xx.xx.xx.xx] 4506 (?) open
```